# Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'd'

Tags: php, regex

I have a function that once in a while gives out an error:

`Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'd'`

Most often it does not. I don't understand the pattern when it does and when it doesn't.

I know almost nothing about regex, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the function:

```
function textHighlight($haystack,$needle,$clr='yellow') {
    $haystack=preg_replace("/($needle)/i","<span style='background:$clr;'>\${1}</span>",$haystack);
    return $haystack;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: how you called this function`textHighlight` and what parameter you passed?

Comment: this is working perfect http://codepad.viper-7.com/gMvunx

Comment: `textHighlight('somestring', '/d');` will reproduce the error described

Comment: like i said, it is working perfect until it doesn't. this function processes about 50 strings, and I usually get about 2 to 5 warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a '/' character in the $needle variable. You can replace /../ with #...#

Comment: Thank you! this worked. For my future education - is there ANY functional difference between enclosing a string in /s as opposed to #s?

Comment: No, AFAIK there is none actually. The regex engine is just getting confused because you have another '/' character in the $needle. I think you can escape each character with '/\' (I'm not pretty sure with that).